# Evaluate multiple repeated measurements (180 measurement)

Tags: repeated-measures, biostatistics

In my research, in which I examined the change in blood pressure according to the treatments applied (2 treatment groups, 1 control group), I obtained 180 measurements for each individual (33 participants were found in each group) in a total of 2 months.

How should I go about evaluating these metrics? I plan to use RM ANOVA or linear mixed model. However, I am confused about the correct approach for such a large number of repeated measurements.

Comment: What is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

I would think a time series analysis would be best. There is a great deal of dependency between measurements based on time, so time is an important factor. You could also consider a linear mixed model, which would allow for dependency within a predictor.

One word of caution: Next time you set out to do a study, you must determine the analysis that you will be conducting before collecting data. An IRB should not have approved this study without a plan of analysis. Determining the analysis before collecting data will help to uncover any experimental design issues.